# JS barcode enter data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 inputs. The first one is #barcode and the second one is #quantity. I'm using a barcode scanner to enter values with Tab key after scanned data. For now I can enter my quantity. Most of time my quantity is null, it's mean 1 peace.

Right now my cursor is on #quantity input. I would like to scan next barcode without click to enter (call ajax, then reset the form). How can I achieve that?

It's easy with 1 input #barcode. Waiting to enter (if (keyCode == 13) {...}), but on this situation I have 2 inputs and the second one can be empty. Is it possible to detect if a value is coming from keyboard or barcode scanner?

I don't want to have more than 2 inputs.

```
<form role="form" method="POST" id="product" action="" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" id="barcode">
  <input type="text" id="quantity">
  <button type="submit" id="create">Create</button>
  <button type="submit" id="clear">Clear</button>
</form>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('#create').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var barcode = $("#barcode").val();
    var quantity = $("#quantity").val();

    quantity = (quantity == null) ? 1 : quantity;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{{ path('product_add') }}",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {proBarcode: barcode, proQuantity: quantity},
      success: function (result) {
        $('#product')[0].reset();
      }
     });
   });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code so we can help.

Comment: _..without click to enter on my keyboard.._  this sounds wierd only to me?

Comment: Try make `$("#barcode").focus()` inside the action method (button click),
otherwise , post your code so we can understand better your probleme

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda updated question

Answer (score 0):

If the barcode scanner automatically "presses tab" after it scanned a code, all you have to do is use tabindexes to make it go to the next #barcode input field (in stead of the #quantity input field).

You may want to use classes in stead of ID's though.

Here is an example that would work with your barcode scanner:

```html
<form>
  
  Barcode: <input type="text" class="barcode" tabindex="1"> | Quantity: <input type="text" class="quantity"><br>
  Barcode: <input type="text" class="barcode" tabindex="2"> | Quantity: <input type="text" class="quantity"><br>
  Barcode: <input type="text" class="barcode" tabindex="3"> | Quantity: <input type="text" class="quantity"><br>
  Barcode: <input type="text" class="barcode" tabindex="4"> | Quantity: <input type="text" class="quantity"><br>
  Barcode: <input type="text" class="barcode" tabindex="5"> | Quantity: <input type="text" class="quantity"><br>
  Barcode: <input type="text" class="barcode" tabindex="6"> | Quantity: <input type="text" class="quantity">
  
</form>
```

Note that when you press TAB on the Barcode field, it will go to the next Barcode field :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using [Scanner Detection plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/scannerdetection/) of jquery.
Using this you can identify whether it's manual or barcode input. You can anywhere on the screen barcode will copied to desired element/textbox even if its not focused

You can detect barcode scan event and based on your requirement you can customize your application. Here is updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5n2p8pzq/12/) where you can play around with this plugin

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    debugger;
    $(window).scannerDetection();

    $(window)
      .bind('scannerDetectionComplete', function(e, data) {
// element where your barcode is to be entered even if its not focused
        $("#barcode").val(data.string);
        console.log("Barcode Scanned" + data.string);

      })
      .bind('scannerDetectionError', function(e, data) {

        console.log("Error in Barcode Scanning");
      })
      .bind('scannerDetectionReceive', function(e, data) {
        console.log("recieving data:" + data);

      })

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Scanner-Detection/master/jquery.scannerdetection.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    Barcode
    <input type='text' id='barcode' />
    <br/>Quantity
    <input type='text' id='qty' />
    <br/>Scanned Barcode
    <input type='text' id='barcodeScanned' />
    <br/>
```